# Dose NOT work JWT Authentication in Python BOXSDK

Tags: python, box-api, box

I want to create a new user via BOXSDK.
But In this code, JWT is dose NOT working.
When Another user is running this code,  it works this code.

```
    from boxsdk import JWTAuth
    from boxsdk import Client
    from boxsdk.config import Proxy
     
    Proxy.URL = 'http://proxy.xxxxx.co.jp:8080'
    
    
    service_account_auth = JWTAuth(
        client_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        jwt_key_id='xxxxx',
        rsa_private_key_file_sys_path='C:\\cygwin64\\home\\private.pem',
        rsa_private_key_passphrase='xxxxx',
        enterprise_id='xxxxxxxxxx',
    )
    
    
    service_account_auth.authenticate_instance()
    service_account_client = Client(service_account_auth)
    new_app_user = service_account_client.create_user('App_User_001', login=None)
    print('The user ID is {0}'.format(new_app_user.id))
    print('The User Mail Address is  {0}'.format(new_app_user.login))
    print('The User Name is  {0}'.format(new_app_user.name)r code here
```

The result is here.

> "Traceback (most recent call last):   File "adduser.py", line 8, in
>
> service_account_auth = JWTAuth( TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

So Anyone, please help.
Thanks regard.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JWTAuth is coming back as a `NoneType`, have you checked your `requirements.txt` file?

https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/issues/387#issuecomment-644344864

You just want to have `boxsdk["jwt"]`